# Responsive Table layout for different size screen android

Tags: android

When I am try to develop a simple table layout it's occur a problem. The layout is works fine for big screen. But when I'm use that in small phone then the problem create. The full rows aren't visible.

Can anyone help me out? I just want to make a simple table layout like that: [image: required layout]

here what I made xml layout

```
               <TableLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/jonosonkha"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:stretchColumns="5">
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:background="#ffea00"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="পরিবার"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="পুরুষ"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#ffea00"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="মহিলা"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="গড় সদস্য"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#ffea00"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="ঘনত্ব/কি.মি"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:background="#ffea00"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="৮৯৮৬৩"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="২০৫০৭৫"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#ffea00"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="২০৯১১৩"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="৪.৫৪"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:background="#ffea00"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:text="২১৩৮"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

It's works fine for big screen but the problem is some of rows are covered by the small screen. Any solution please.

Comment: try gridview instead

Comment: a brief detail help much more . do you have sample code of required image?

Comment: you can use tablelayout inside horizontal scrollview. have a look at this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25460375/4824088

Comment: i don't need scrolling option. i just need a table like that image. but responsive i mean it's should be work with every device screen size. specially with smaller one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to divide five `TextView` .

You can add `android:layout_width="0dp"` 、`android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in your `TextView` .

You can try this .

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/jonosonkha"
    android:stretchColumns="5">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffea00"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="পরিবার"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="পুরুষ"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffea00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="মহিলা"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="গড় সদস্য"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffea00"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="ঘনত্ব/কি.মি"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffea00"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="৮৯৮৬৩"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="২০৫০৭৫"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffea00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="২০৯১১৩"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="৪.৫৪"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffea00"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="২১৩৮"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: it's works fine for me. here is one little problem. the long text(in the title) is get break down in two line. is there any way to keep them in one line?

Comment: You just change the size of `TextView` .Because you space is 1/5 of your screen .

Comment: Good luck to you .@MamunNayeem

Answer (score 0):

You should define the width attribute of the table rows, like:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

and the weight attribute of all the Textviews:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="#ffea00"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="পরিবার"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
```